# I can't perform a logistic regression in R

Tags: r, linear-regression, logistic-regression

This is the head of the dataset

```r
structure(list(Round = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), upset = c(0, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 0), seed_diff = c(15, 13, 11, 9, 7, 5), score_diff = c(26, 
30, 7, -11, 5, -10), GP = c(38, 40, 35, 34, 36, 34), MPG = c(40.5, 
40.1, 40.1, 40.4, 40.2, 40.9), PPG = c(81.3, 78, 75.2, 74.9, 
75.7, 80.4), FGA = c(58.1, 56.2, 54.1, 56.8, 53.9, 57.9), FG. = c(0.495, 
0.483, 0.479, 0.461, 0.486, 0.48), X3PA = c(19.2, 24, 18.4, 19.1, 
20.5, 17.1), X3P. = c(0.418, 0.362, 0.375, 0.363, 0.361, 0.381
), FTA = c(22.2, 19.1, 22.1, 23.7, 20.7, 25.4), FT. = c(0.713, 
0.782, 0.749, 0.656, 0.768, 0.721), ORB = c(9.9, 8.3, 9, 10.5, 
8.5, 10.9), DRB = c(26.8, 25.1, 24.3, 27.5, 25.8, 28.1), APG = c(15.9, 
15.9, 12.5, 12.7, 13.6, 14.3), SPG = c(6.7, 7, 6.1, 4.1, 5.8, 
4.8), BPG = c(4.2, 3.4, 3.6, 4.7, 5.4, 4.7), TOV = c(12.6, 11, 
10.9, 12.2, 12.8, 13), PF = c(18.9, 17, 16.6, 20.8, 16.8, 18.3
)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(Round = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), upset = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), seed_diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), score_diff = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), GP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), MPG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), PPG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), FGA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), FG. = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), X3PA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), X3P. = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), FTA = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), FT. = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), ORB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), DRB = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), APG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), SPG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), BPG = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), TOV = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), PF = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

I am trying to do a logistic regression on the binary variable "upset"

I tried this

```r
fit <- lm(upset~Round+seed_diff+score_diff+GP+MPG+PPG+FGA+FG.+X3PA+X3P.+FTA+FT.+ORB+DRB+APG+SPG+BPG+TOV+PF ,data=AllTeamTotal)
summary(fit)
vcov(fit)
plot(fitted(fit),residuals(fit))
abline(h=0,lty=2)

head(AllTeamTotalR)

logfit<-lm(log(upset)~Round+seed_diff+score_diff+GP+MPG+PPG+FGA+FG.+X3PA+X3P.+FTA+FT.+ORB+DRB+APG+SPG+BPG+TOV+PF,data=AllTeamTotal)
plot(fitted(logfit),residuals(logfit))
```

and the fit model worked, but when I tried the log model it came up as

> Error in lm.fit(x, y, offset = offset, singular.ok = singular.ok, ...) :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

so I tried a glm log but then it came up as

> Error in glm.fit(x = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,  :
> NA/NaN/Inf in 'y'

How do I solve this!?

Comment: You might have an issue with `log(0) = -Inf`.

Comment: "Might have an issue"? I don't there's a great deal of uncertainty on that point.

Comment: Read this thread on _Cross Validated_: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1444/how-should-i-transform-non-negative-data-including-zeros

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, you do not seem to be properly running a logistic regression. For a basic logistic regression, you should use `glm()` and specify the `family` as binomial:

```
## defined your data as `df`

# define formula, for convenience
fmla <- as.formula(upset ~ Round + seed_diff + score_diff + GP + MPG + PPG + FGA + FG. + X3PA + X3P. + FTA + FT. + ORB + DRB + APG + SPG + BPG + TOV + PF)

glm(fmla, data = df, family = "binomial")

# Call:  glm(formula = fmla, family = binomial, data = df)
# 
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)        Round    seed_diff   score_diff           GP          MPG          PPG          FGA  
# -13395.190           NA        3.574        4.263        3.910      411.838      -44.549           NA  
# FG.         X3PA         X3P.          FTA          FT.          ORB          DRB          APG  
# NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA           NA  
# SPG          BPG          TOV           PF  
# NA           NA           NA           NA  
# 
# Degrees of Freedom: 5 Total (i.e. Null);  0 Residual
# Null Deviance:        5.407 
# Residual Deviance: 2.572e-10  AIC: 12
```